# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "srtserversink"

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I am using gstreamer to test SRT, like this

> gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw, height=1080, width=1920 \
>       ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! video/x-h264, profile=high \
>       ! mpegtsmux ! srtserversink uri=srt://:8888/

just got :

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "srtserversink"

What do I miss?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The warning `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "srtserversink"` means that your system is missing the GStreamer plugin corresponding to `srtserversink`. Are you sure that there is no typo in the element name. Try running the following to search if the plugin exists in your system:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 srtserversink
```

If this does not yield details about the plugin, then try `grep`ing the plugin using:

```
gst-inspect-1.0  grep srt*
```

This may give you the exact name of the element you want.

If the above does not work, that means the plugin is not yet installed in your system. You may have to find the right packages for your plugin and install it. I believe the package you would want to install is `gst-plugins-bad`